# How to add a validation rule to the Ace editor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I have implemented the Ace editor into my web page, and I use it to write JavaScript functions.

My page works just fine, I made a small parser for some reasons, the parser can get everything done, but not the comment if it is declared with the following characters: `//`

I can read the large comments: `/* some code */`

but not the normal one: `// some code`

So I need to prevent the user to type the normal comment(`//`) in the console.

So I need a validation rule to add to the editor. And I work in JavaScript and AngularJS.

Here is some code of mine how I added the editor:

Controller:

```
editor = ace.edit("fileInfo");
var JavaScriptMode = ace.require("ace/mode/javascript").Mode;
editor.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode());
```

HTML page:

```
<div id="top-content">
    <div style="width: 100%;height:100%; top:6px;" id="fileInfo">   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you'll need another parser to warn about //, so it would be much easier to fix your parser to support //, than to warn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

Comment: and what is that gonna do? I mean, that is not going to validate my comment problems :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can hook into the Ace editor's change event and alert the user when they start a line with //. There would be several use cases that you would have to handle correctly:

a. The obvious one - ignoring white space, the previous non-empty line ends with a ; and this starts with // - so alert the user; but

b. User has missed a semi-colon from the previous line.

c. We are inside a multi-line quoted string or inside a /* */ comment.

d. etc.

So hooking the change event is easy but deciding when to alert the user is trickier. See https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session for Ace API details.

P.S. As an alternative to preventing a // comment, why not turn it into a /* */ comment when the user moves to a new line?